# Excel, two columns, date comparison, specific month

Tags: excel

I have two columns containing dates.
I need to count how many times dates in column A are unequal to column B, and I want to be able to specify for which month I want it to count.

Have tried various versions of CountIF(s) and Sumproduct but have so far been unsuccessful - anyone got a suggestion?

=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A3<>B1:B3)) works for the counting, but not specific month.

```
   A        B         C          D  
Actual   Appoint.   Month      Count  
03Feb18  03Feb18    February     2  
10Feb18  15Feb18  
18Feb18  15Feb18
```

Comment: Please clarify... Are your col A & B date formats?  You're probably needing `countifs()` -- Post the equations that you tried... it's easier for the community to validate and respond.

Comment: They are date formats, yeah.  
The Sumproduct I use works, but not for specific month.  
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A14<>B1:B14))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4<>B2:B4)*(TEXT(A2:A4,"mmmm")=C2))
```

This is for cases where the Actual month is February (the appointment could be March, say) - could be modified to count cases where one or both of actual and appointment fall in February.

[image]